# How to setup mina2 hl7Codec in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, mina

Need help from experts. I am new to learn apcahe camel. I have configured camel to spring boot application. Now i want to add mina2 protocol. I have found below code for configuring mina2 for xml, but how to i add this in my spring boot application?

```html
<bean id="hl7codec" class="org.apache.camel.component.hl7.HL7MLLPCodec">
    <property name="charset" value="iso-8859-1"/>
</bean>
```

If i don't add this configuration it will through exception below:

```html
Exception in thread "CamelMainRunController" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route2: Route(route2)[[From[mina2:tcp://0.0.0.0:4001?sync=true&codec... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: mina2://tcp://0.0.0.0:4001?codec=%23hl7codec&sync=true due to: Could not find a suitable setter for property: codec as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFactory with value #hl7codec
 at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootApplicationController.run(CamelSpringBootApplicationController.java:85)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelMainRunController$DaemonTask.run(CamelMainRunController.java:53)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route2: Route(route2)[[From[mina2:tcp://0.0.0.0:4001?sync=true&codec... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: mina2://tcp://0.0.0.0:4001?codec=%23hl7codec&sync=true due to: Could not find a suitable setter for property: codec as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFactory with value #hl7codec
 at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:209)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:1087)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3544)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3275)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:202)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3093)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3089)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3112)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:3089)
 at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:3026)
 at org.apache.camel.main.Main.doStart(Main.java:129)
 at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
 at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:168)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootApplicationController.run(CamelSpringBootApplicationController.java:80)
 ... 2 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: mina2://tcp://0.0.0.0:4001?codec=%23hl7codec&sync=true due to: Could not find a suitable setter for property: codec as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFactory with value #hl7codec
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:723)
 at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:80)
 at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:219)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:112)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:118)
 at org.apache.camel.model.FromDefinition.resolveEndpoint(FromDefinition.java:69)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.getEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:94)
 at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1278)
 at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:204)
 ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a suitable setter for property: codec as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFactory with value #hl7codec
 at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperty(IntrospectionSupport.java:614)
 at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperty(IntrospectionSupport.java:640)
 at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperties(IntrospectionSupport.java:497)
 at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperties(IntrospectionSupport.java:507)
 at org.apache.camel.util.EndpointHelper.setProperties(EndpointHelper.java:256)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.setProperties(DefaultComponent.java:299)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.setProperties(DefaultComponent.java:287)
 at org.apache.camel.component.mina2.Mina2Component.createEndpoint(Mina2Component.java:71)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:116)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:676)
 ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have found my own question answer. The answer is below:

```html
@Bean
 public CamelContext contex() {
  CamelContext camelContext;
  SimpleRegistry reg = new SimpleRegistry();
  reg.put("hl7codec", new HL7MLLPCodec());
  camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(reg);
  return camelContext;
  
 }
```

Use this code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks that code works but I placed this in a CamelContextConfiguration Bean

```
  @Bean
CamelContextConfiguration contextConfiguration() {
    return new CamelContextConfiguration() {

        @Override
        public void beforeApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {

            final org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry registry = new org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry();
            final org.apache.camel.impl.CompositeRegistry compositeRegistry = new org.apache.camel.impl.CompositeRegistry();
            compositeRegistry.addRegistry(camelContext.getRegistry());
            compositeRegistry.addRegistry(registry);
            ((org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext) camelContext).setRegistry(compositeRegistry);
            registry.put("hl7codec", new HL7MLLPCodec());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {

        }
    };
}
```